# OpenXML C# read .docx

Tags: c#, openxml

Пытаюсь получить **весь** текст из документа *.docx*.

```
using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName as string, false))
            {
                //получаем весь текст
                var text = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;                    
                Console.WriteLine(rawText);
            }
```

Весь текст действительно получается и записывается в переменную, но, он получается не форматированным и на выходе получаем что-то типа этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в самом word'овском файле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагал, что при получении текста он будет хотя бы с учетом перевода строки, но оказалось все не так просто.

Какие есть варианты, чтобы перевод строки сохранялся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте таким способом:

```
public string GetPlainText(OpenXmlElement element) 
{ 
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); 
    foreach (OpenXmlElement section in element.Elements()) 
    {              
        switch (section.LocalName) 
        { 
            // Text 
            case "t":  
                PlainTextInWord.Append(section.InnerText); 
                break; 
            case "cr":                          // Carriage return 
            case "br":                          // Page break 
                PlainTextInWord.Append(Environment.NewLine); 
                break; 
                // Tab 
            case "tab": 
                PlainTextInWord.Append("\t"); 
                break; 
            // Paragraph 
            case "p": 
                PlainTextInWord.Append(GetPlainText(section)); 
                PlainTextInWord.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine); 
                break; 
            default: 
                PlainTextInWord.Append(GetPlainText(section)); 
                break; 
        } 
    } 
    return text.ToString();
}

var text = GetPlainText(wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body);                    
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

[Источник](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOpenXmlGetPlainText-554918c3)